# Overriding a JS file from server from proxy

Tags: proxy, javascript

I have an Apache reverse-proxy server set up between a client machine and a server. What I want to achieve is to override a javascript file sent from the server with the one from the proxy before sending the file to the client. I don't want to change the javascript file at the server because I want the proxy to be transparent. Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a the [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) Apache directive you can exclude certain sub directories and file system paths from being forwarded by using an exclamation mark `!`. That will allow you to serve them from the local file system on the proxy server instead.

```
 # Exclude file.js and serve that from the local filesystem
 ProxyPass /app/dir/file.js !
 # proxy /app to internal server
 ProxyPass /app http://int.example.com/app
 ProxyPassReverse /app http://int.example.com/app
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.